# select all checkbox when header checkbox selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, gridview, checkbox

I am trynig to select all checkbox when header checkbox is selected.

I write proper code for that but do'nt know why it's not working.

Can anyone check the issue.

My code--

```
    <head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function SelectAllCheckboxes1(chk) {
            $('#<%=GridView1.ClientID%>').find("input:checkbox").each(function () {
                if (this != chk) { this.checked = chk.checked; }
            });
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:gridview ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
            DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <HeaderTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="cbSelectAll" runat="server" onclick="javascript:SelectAllCheckboxes1(this);" AutoPostBack="true"/>    
                    </HeaderTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="chk" runat="server" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name" />
            </Columns>   
        </asp:gridview>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:HRMSConnectionString %>" 
            SelectCommand="SELECT [Name] FROM [Languages]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Do u want to do it with javascript ?? ....

Comment: No particular language....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code-

**default.aspx.cs**

```
protected void sellectAll(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CheckBox ChkBoxHeader = (CheckBox)GridView1.HeaderRow.FindControl("chkb1");
    foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
    {
        CheckBox ChkBoxRows = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("chkb2");
        if (ChkBoxHeader.Checked == true)
        {
            ChkBoxRows.Checked = true;
        }
        else
        {
            ChkBoxRows.Checked = false;
        }
    }
}
```

**Change grid code-**

```
 <asp:gridview ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <HeaderTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkb1" runat="server"  AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="sellectAll"/>    
                </HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkb2" runat="server" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name" />
        </Columns>   
    </asp:gridview>
```

Comment: Your code will work, but I think OP was trying to get this done though javascript or jquery?